# Anviz Devices, "Device timeout waiting response"

Tags: .net, github, sdk, connection

I'm trying to connect the Anviz C2 Pro device to the Anviz.SDK from GitHub. When I attempt to connect the device to the .NET library, I'm encountering a timeout issue while waiting for a response. I have connected the device via Ethernet, and the gateway is set to the same IP address as my laptop.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F27Lc.png), Here is the example of how I have the connection in .NET

I have already tried connecting to other networks and changing the IP address. I also tested the Official Anviz SDK, and it successfully establishes a connection, but the Anviz.SDK from GitHub doesn´t works